# Permissions using a tablist in PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I have a tablist containing 4 departments, I want to setup permissions for those tabs based off the users department, the connectors I am using which is Office365User. If a user selects a department that is not theirs a error message displays saying the don't have permission. The department information is located within a container which is then displayed using the visible function, so if the tab manufacturing is selected then the container appears.

TabList1.Selected.TabName = "Accounting" And Office365Users.MyProfile().Department = "Accounting"
If(Office365Users.MyProfile().Department <> "Accounting" Navigate(NoPermission)

I have tried this on the visible function of the container I want to display when the correct tab is clicked

The tablist also provides the OnSelect function, just unsure how to set separate parameters per tab